# Get Key from a Value (Where value is in a list)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have dictionary like this

```
my_dict={'0':['A','B','C'],'1':['D','E','F']}
```

How can I access the key using one of the value if value is a list ?

Comment: You should have read about [python's dict structure](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) first before coming here.

Comment: @baduker That dosen't seem to answer my question mate

Comment: And this should be on your reading list too [how much research effort is expected on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
>>> def corresponding_key(val, dictionary):
        for k, v in dictionary.items():
            if val in v:
                return k

>>> corresponding_key("A", my_dict)
'0'
>>> corresponding_key("B", my_dict)
'0'
>>> corresponding_key("C", my_dict)
'0'
>>> corresponding_key("D", my_dict)
'1'
>>> corresponding_key("E", my_dict)
'1'
>>> corresponding_key("F", my_dict)
'1'
>>>
```

However, in the case where a value is in multiple dictionary value lists, you can modify the function:

```py
>>> def corresponding_keys(val, dictionary):
        keys = []
        for k, v in dictionary.items():
            if val in v:
                keys.append(k)
        return keys
```

Or, you could use list comprehension:

```py
>>> val = "A"
>>> dictionary = my_dict
>>> [k for k, v in dictionary.items() if val in v]
['0']
```

Comment: Which one is best in performance ? (Just Curious)

Comment: @ConMan77 I would rank them (in order of best performance to least performance): **1, 3, 2**. I may be wrong, but here's my logic: Number 1 does not have to parse through every key-value pair, as it returns immediately once a match if found; Number 3 uses list comprehension, which is generally faster than function calling, but must iterate over every pair; Number 2 combines the worst of 1 and 3, where it is a function call and must iterate through each pair, plus the added memory taken by the list variable `keys`.